# Rails 3 correct image_tag conversion

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parallax

I'm trying to convert parallax effect code to run on a Rails 3 app. I can't get it to run so I'm wondering if I've converted this code properly. The first line in each group is the original code. The second line in each group is my conversion. Can anyone tell me if this is right?

```
<article class="slide" id="showcasing" style="background:   url('backgrounds/landscape.png') repeat-x top center;">
<%= image_tag("backgrounds/landscape.png", :class => "slide", :id => "showcasing", :style => "background: repeat-x top center") %>

<img class="asset left-30 sp600 t120 z1" src="slides/scene1/macbook.png" />
<%= image_tag("slides/scene1/macbook.png", :class => "asset: left-30 sp600 t120 z1") %>

<article class="slide" id="ideas" style="background: url('backgrounds/aqua.jpg') repeat-x top center;">
<%= image_tag("backgrounds/aqua.jpg", :class => "slide", :id => "ideas", :style => "background: url('backgrounds/aqua.jpg') repeat-x top center") %>

<img class="asset left-480 sp600 t260 z1" src="img/slides/scene2/left.png" />
<%= image_tag("slides/scene2/left.png", :class => "asset left-480 sp600 t260 z1") %>

<img class="asset left-210 sp600 t213 z2" src="img/slides/scene2/middle.png" />
<%= image_tag("slides/scene2/middle.png", :class => "asset left-210 sp600 t213 z2") %>

<img class="asset left60 sp600 t260 z1" src="img/slides/scene2/right.png" />
<%= image_tag("slides/scene2/right.png", :class => "asset left60 sp600 t260 z1") %>
```

Comment: You don't need to use ERB if your HTML is static so all of your first lines are fine as-is.

Comment: I was thinking I needed to change it to ERB because the parallax effect was not working.

Comment: @user2358800 all `image_tag` will do is render into a static image tag which you've already got. You'll need to debug further via browser console. View the source and be sure the `image_tag` is rendering the correct html.

Comment: Are the image paths correct? Any errors in the server logs or in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Everyone with an `<article>` tag was not right, because `image_tag` only yield `<img />` tag. You should use `image_path` to yield a url and place it in `style="background: url()"` ([image_path API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path)).

Other code should be like:

```
<%= image_tag("slides/scene1/macbook.png", :class => "asset left-30 sp600 t120 z1") %>
```

Comment: I corrected the <article> tag as you suggested and now those images show up. But on the second line the images don't show up unless I remove the :class section. Then the image is just static, no effect. Does this mean that the js is not being read?

Comment: @user2358800 the second image_tag has a extra `:` after `"asset"` in the :class value, you can try remove it.

Comment: The only way the image shows on screen is if I delete the :class section from the line. This is true for every "image_tag" line. Why is this? What am I missing. These are part of flexslider, but it's not working.